# Recreating a local repository from a currently existing wordpress.org repo..which I own

Tags: plugins, svn, repository, plugin-repository

Sorry for the name. Not sure how to succinctly title this one.

I have a plugin available on the WordPress.org repo. It's the Encrypt Email plugin.

The laptop I was using to develop/maintain it died. Now I want to resume development of on my work pc. But I'm not sure how.

So how can I clone/pull the repo to my machine so I can resume pushing and committing future changes from where I left off? (As if I was still on my dead Laptop's repo)

I have TortoiseSVN and can SVN from the commandline so either explanation is fine (I prefer shell to be honest).

I have a lot of Git experience so explaining with comparisons to Git commands and workflows would be really helpful for me also.

Huge thank you for any help on this one!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this URL format for checkout (if using TortoiseSVN, just right click and do checkout from Explorer):

`http://plugins.svn.wordpress.org/your-plugin-name`

You will need to use your username/password for WordPress (the account used to publish the plugin) to do any commits.

Command line instructions are available direct from WordPress here: https://wordpress.org/plugins/about/svn/

Comment: Thanks. I'd read the WordPress SVn article but I was thinking I'd have to do something like Git where you need to create an SSH key and all that again. Overthinking it.